# PHP - Query database for pending messages and call PHPmailer without refresh

Tags: php, ajax

I am using phpMailer, and i have a database table "list" with columns id|name|email|status.

What i am doing currently is using the phpMailer example

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail                = new PHPMailer();

$body                = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body                = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$id = $_GET['id'];

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host          = "smtp1.xample.com;smtp2.xample.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth      = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;                  // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent
$mail->Host          = "mail.example.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port          = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username      = "no-reply@example.com"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password      = "password";        // SMTP account password
$mail->SetFrom('no-reply@example.com', 'Honda example');
$mail->AddReplyTo('no-reply@example.com', 'Honda example');

$mail->Subject       = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

@MYSQL_CONNECT("localhost","root","password");
@mysql_select_db("osher");
$query  = "SELECT full_name, email, photo FROM employee WHERE id=$id";
$result = @MYSQL_QUERY($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
  $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);
  $mail->AddAddress($row["email"], $row["full_name"]);
  $mail->AddStringAttachment($row["photo"], "YourPhoto.jpg");

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row["email"]) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
  } else {
    echo "Message sent to :" . $row["full_name"] . ' (' . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row["email"]) . ')<br />';
  }
  // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
  $mail->ClearAddresses();
  $mail->ClearAttachments();
}
```

Now the code above is `db-email.php` Where in if my table, email has over 100 entries with status as pending, i want to be able to using php. select each rows id and call `db-email.php?id=xx` (where x is the id) hence the email gets sent.

This works fine, if its done manually.

i needed you guys to help me, how best I can automate this process, that is to be able to push this 100 emails (without having to refresh the page)

assuming, I am on `email.php` where I can probably hit (a button) and it would simply start processing, each of the row in the email table, (instead of echo'n the result) I will be updating the database with status to = 'sent'

I am not sure if I have been very clear on what I want to ask, Please do help friends.
I believe someone with expertise in jQuery/AJAX or something could help me achieve this task :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your trying to do but, you can't do anything with databases or servers via **javascript** or **jquery** because there **executed in the browser** and **not on the server**.
You could use `ajax` to call certain `.php` files on the server with some parameters to do your job !

Comment: What i was trying to say was. I have a file email.php (where i query the database table for rows with status pending) retrieve its id value, and want to be able to put it in a for or while loop, and query the above code file (example i added above) , and continue doing so. until the status=pending returns = 0 count. (all this without redirecting or refreshing, from the file email.php)   ;-)